# Vector field with parallel field lines

Tags: vector-analysis

If the field lines of vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y)$ are parallel, what can be said about the divergence and curl of the field? I think the curl must be zero but divergence can get value.

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyze these vector fields to discover what can happen:

${\bf F_1}(x,y)=(y,0)$

${\bf F_2}(x,y)=(x,0)$

${\bf F_3}(x,y)=(xy,0)$

${\bf F_4}(x,y)=(1,0)$

Comment: Is $f(x,y)$ the scalar potential of $\mathbf{F}$? what is $g(x,y)$?

Comment: @ELEC No, I just meant them to be function names for two different vector fields. I'm going to change them to be boldface capitals, since that's what you seem to be comfortable with.

Comment: I'm still not sure how. We don't know $\mathbf{F}$ so how can evaluate it's value in a point. And how does curl and divergence come into play. Sorry, i'm a little lost.

Comment: @ELEC I don't understand. I defined **F** for my example, so why do you say "we don't know it"? ${\bf F}(1,0)=(0,0)$, ${\bf F}(0,1)=(1,0)$, ${\bf F}(20,-5)=(-5,0)$, are some examples of evaluating this vector function. Now you can compute the divergence and curls of each of these fields and see what happens.

Comment: For continuity, the last comment was written back when $F_1$ was simply $F$.

Comment: Ahhh yes you provided vector fields that have parallel field lines. I'm was just confused with the notation. I used to $<a,b>$